# How to get (single) prediction values & linear regression summaries from 2 dataframes in R

Tags: r, function, linear-regression, predict, tibble

I'm trying to get a prediction values for univariate analysis on these data frames:

X Variables

```
structure(list(GDP.SC = c(154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 
154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698), GDP.SC1 = c(NA, 154698, 
154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698
), GDP.SC2 = c(NA, NA, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 
154698, 154698, 154698), GDP.SC3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 154698, 154698, 
154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698), GDP.SC4 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698), CivilianLaborForce.SC = c(1938335L, 
1941025L, 1944162L, 1947433L, 1950188L, 1952687L, 1956061L, 1960701L, 
1966380L, 1972351L), CivilianLaborForce.SC1 = c(NA, 1938335L, 
1941025L, 1944162L, 1947433L, 1950188L, 1952687L, 1956061L, 1960701L, 
1966380L), CivilianLaborForce.SC2 = c(NA, NA, 1938335L, 1941025L, 
1944162L, 1947433L, 1950188L, 1952687L, 1956061L, 1960701L), 
    CivilianLaborForce.SC3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1938335L, 1941025L, 
    1944162L, 1947433L, 1950188L, 1952687L, 1956061L), CivilianLaborForce.SC4 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1938335L, 1941025L, 1944162L, 1947433L, 1950188L, 
    1952687L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Y Variables:

```
structure(list(CommercialB = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.004, 
0.012, 0.007, NA), CommercialNOO = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.006, 0.027, NA, NA), CommercialIOO = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), ConsumerO = c(0.011, 0.011, 0.021, 0.021, 0.027, 0.032, 
0.027, 0.027, 0.025, 0.027), ConsumerRE = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), Heloc = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.005, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 
0.004, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Method of getting Summary for Univariate Linear Regression:

```
fit_sum1 <- function(yvar, xdf) {
  # ITERATE THROUGH EACH COLUMN OF x
  df_list <- lapply(seq_along(xdf), function(i) {
    n <- lm(yvar ~ x[,i]) #Regression
    m <- coef(summary(n))       #Summary for Model 
    data.frame(
      Variable = names(x)[i],            # print variable name
      Intercept = m[1,1],   # intercept
      Coefficient = m[2,1], # coefficient
      P_val = m[2,4],      # Pvalue
      Intuitive = ifelse(m[2,1]>0,"Yes","No"), #Intuitive YN
      Significance  = ifelse(m[2,4]<.15,"Yes","-"), #Significance YN
      Prediction = predict(n,type = "response")  #Predict Function####
    )
  })
  return(do.call(rbind, df_list))
}
y.df <- lapply(y, function(col) fit_sum1(col, x)) #Iterate through Y df
```

Im having trouble understanding why the predict function repeats the x variables in this summary.

```
> head(y.df$CommercialB)
   Variable  Intercept   Coefficient        P_val Intuitive Significance Prediction
7    GDP.SC 0.04283477 -1.944471e-07 0.0004347055        No          Yes 0.01275419
8    GDP.SC 0.04283477 -1.944471e-07 0.0004347055        No          Yes 0.01275419
9    GDP.SC 0.04283477 -1.944471e-07 0.0004347055        No          Yes 0.01275419
11   GDP.SC 0.04283477 -1.944471e-07 0.0004347055        No          Yes 0.01169632
12   GDP.SC 0.04283477 -1.944471e-07 0.0004347055        No          Yes 0.01169632
13   GDP.SC 0.04283477 -1.944471e-07 0.0004347055        No          Yes 0.01169632
>
```

I know that the predict function will return a vector, but I think I am missing something on exactly how the function works. 
As for the example, is there a more efficient way to get predictions from the model for individual values passed from each data frame? 
My goal is to get an output like this (with the prediction values at the end):

```
> head(y.df$CommercialB)   ##### function without predict  ########
               Variable  Intercept   Coefficient        P_val Intuitive Significance
1                GDP.SC 0.04283477 -1.944471e-07 0.0004347055        No          Yes
2               GDP.SC1 0.04243394 -1.924564e-07 0.0005505297        No          Yes
3               GDP.SC2 0.04197888 -1.901651e-07 0.0006979945        No          Yes
4               GDP.SC3 0.04168221 -1.887271e-07 0.0007952792        No          Yes
5               GDP.SC4 0.04199046 -1.907528e-07 0.0008185224        No          Yes
6 CivilianLaborForce.SC 0.04348104 -1.611569e-08 0.0285751028        No          Yes
```

Comment: Take a look at `broom` package. It has some functions that will provide the output in a tidy format.

Comment: I tried using the ```augment()``` but got no luck for some reason when I pass ```augment.lm()``` I get error: augment.lm can not be found.